# Seg fault when adding an Edge Node to a Vertex that has no Edges

Tags: c++

So first off I know as the title says exactly where my segmentation fault occurs. When I try to add an EdgeNode to a vertex that has no edges to it. I'm bolding the line and if someone could tell me why this is not working.

```
struct EdgeNode                                   
{
  VertexNode*   destination;                       
  int           weight;                            
  EdgeNode*     nextEdge;                           
};

struct VertexNode                                             
{
   string        vname;                            
   bool          mark;                               
   EdgeNode*     edgePtr;                            
   VertexNode*   nextVertex;                         
};

VertexNode* vertices = NULL;

void Graph::AddVertex(string v)
{
   VertexNode* newVertexPtr;
   VertexNode*  tempPtr;
   newVertexPtr = new VertexNode;
   newVertexPtr->vname = v;
   newVertexPtr->nextVertex = NULL;
   newVertexPtr->edgePtr = NULL;

   tempPtr = vertices;

   if ( tempPtr == NULL)
   {
     vertices = newVertexPtr;
     vertices->nextVertex = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
       while ( tempPtr->nextVertex != NULL)
       {
          tempPtr = tempPtr->nextVertex;
       }
     tempPtr->nextVertex = newVertexPtr;
   }

 }

 void Graph::AddEdge(string s, string d, int w)
 {
    EdgeNode* newEdgeNodePtr;
    EdgeNode* tempEdgePtr; 

    VertexNode* tempVerticePtr;
    VertexNode* dVerticePtr;

    tempVerticePtr = vertices;
    dVerticePtr = vertices;  

    try
    {
        newEdgeNodePtr = new EdgeNode;
        delete newEdgeNodePtr;
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc)
    {
       throw GraphFull();
    }

    newEdgeNodePtr = new EdgeNode;
    newEdgeNodePtr->weight = w;
    newEdgeNodePtr->nextEdge = NULL;

    while(dVerticePtr != NULL)
    {
          if(dVerticePtr->vname != d)
             dVerticePtr = dVerticePtr->nextVertex;
          else if(dVerticePtr->vname == d)
          {
              newEdgeNodePtr->destination = dVerticePtr;
              break;
          }

     }

  while(tempVerticePtr != NULL)
  {
     if(tempVerticePtr->vname != s)
     {
         tempVerticePtr = tempVerticePtr->nextVertex;
     }

     if(tempVerticePtr->vname == s)
     {
         if ( tempVerticePtr->edgePtr == NULL)
         {
             ***//tempVerticePtr->edgePtr = newEdgeNodePtr***;
         }
      if ( tempVerticePtr->edgePtr != NULL)
      {
          while ( tempVerticePtr->edgePtr != NULL)
          {
              tempVerticePtr->edgePtr =  tempVerticePtr->edgePtr->nextEdge;    
          }
          tempVerticePtr->edgePtr->nextEdge = newEdgeNodePtr;
      }  
      break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you are saying that this line is the issue?              ***//tempVerticePtr->edgePtr = newEdgeNodePtr***;

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the problem that you are having isn't at the specified line of code you have highlighted for us.

The problem is in the following lines of code :

```
if(tempVerticePtr->vname != s)
{
     tempVerticePtr = tempVerticePtr->nextVertex;
}

if(tempVerticePtr->vname == s)
{
    if ( tempVerticePtr->edgePtr == NULL)
    {
        ***//tempVerticePtr->edgePtr = newEdgeNodePtr***;
    }
    ...
}
```

From what I understand, you are iterating through a linked list via the variable `tempVerticePtr`. In the first if statement, if `vname` does not equal to your parameter `s`, you iterate to the next vertex in your linked list (note that the value of `tempVerticePtr` may be `NULL` from that point).

The problem arises in the second if statement. In the case of `tempVerticePtr` being `NULL`, your if statement will try to check the `vname` of a `NULL` pointer, which would most likely break your program.

The fix in this case would be replacing `if (...)` with `else if (...)`.

Comment: so instead of if(tempVerticePtr->edgePtr == NULL) say else if ?

Comment: @dan Not that one. Instead of if (tempVerticePtr->vname == s), say else if (tempVerticePtr->vname == s)

Comment: Ok so it i replaced it and still get a segfault .. I was able to see though that when i print out tempVerticePtr its printing its memory address so i know its being created.. Any ideas on what could still be causing the fault when this first edge is being created and attempts to be linked by the vertex?

Comment: Update actually just figured it out it was the same mistake in both places by not having an else if on the check if its == s and  again later where its tempVerticePtr->edgePtr != NULL .... thank you for point in the right direction